# Нужно изменить стили, прописанные в navbar.less

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка, less

Написал `html`, `css` и `js`. Верстка работает, как было сказано заказчиком. Но как только я собрался перенести верстку на wordpress, некоторые стили сбились из-за подключения `.less` файлов, то есть препроцессора (к примеру, до того, как поставил верстку на `WordPress`, цвет шрифта был белый, а после - стал черный благодаря `.less`).

Как сделать так, чтобы стили не заменялись? Просто переписать те классы, которые прописаны в `.less` не получается, стили не меняются. Возможно можно как-то отключить этот `less` и все, что с ним связано? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: я не пользуюсь less но разве он не должен генерировать css ? вот его как раз то и надо подключать

Comment: Да я тоже не пользовался. Раньше писал верстку без бутстрапа, решил попробовать сделать с ним. Понял, что намного легче и круче все получается. Все было отлично, стили не сбивались и т.д., если открывать html-файлик, к которому подключены css стили. Поставил этот файлик на Вордпресс и многое слетело, потому что автоматически подключился less.

Answer (score 3):

`SASS/LESS` работают таким образом:

1. Вы пишете в их файлах некий код, который может быть как чистым `css`, так и кодом, соблюдающим правила написания именно для упомянутых технологий;
2. Некий `watcher` (либо вручную) смотрит за изменениями этих файлов, либо просто по некоему расписанию, компилирует написанный код в обычные файлы `css`;
3. Эти файлы сохраняются в те или иные директории, заменяя там уже существующие `css`-файлы.

Таким образом, нет ничего удивительного в том, что если ваш клиент использует у себя на сервере `SASS/LESS`, то их компиляция в итоге затирает результаты вашей работы.

Выходов тут может быть три:

1. Отключить использование данных технологий, но, возможно, это не устроит вашего заказчика, как именно это сделать я смогу сказать после того, как вы более подробно обозначите конфигурацию проекта;
2. Встроить ваш код в компилируемые файлы, и таким образом при компиляции он будет попадать вместе с остальным кодом, там содержащимся, по месту назначения;
3. Использовать отдельные `css`-файлы для вашего кода и для компилируемого кода, либо удалив из последнего те части, которые пересекаются с вашим кодом (может быть весьма трудозатратно), либо подключая ваши файлы последними, таким образом перезаписывая нужные вам правила.

На мой взгляд, самый верный путь - это пункт 3, первый вариант в нем. Но какой устроит вас, сказать сложно, без взгляда на проект целиком и общения с вашим заказчиком.

Comment: Я слышал, что подключать много css-файлов нельзя, потому что легче загрузить единый файл стилей, чем загружать много и по отдельности. Или это не так?
По поводу замены стилей less - я за, вообще так бы и хотелось, честно говоря, но я не знаю, где эти файлы найти. Они видны только в браузере, и в браузере я их могу менять, но не знаю, можно ли их сохранить через браузер.

Comment: @HoFTeR Подключать много файлов можно без проблем, собирать их в один единый есть смысл только на проектах, где есть проблемы со скоростью загрузки сайта (обычно это либо сайты с высокой посещаемостью, либо сайты на каком-нибудь WP с пол сотней подключенных плагинов).

Comment: @HoFTeR а что касается файлов LESS - можно подробнее, как их видно в браузере и почему их нет на хостинге? И сразу такой момент - проверь, есть ли у тебя в папке, где лежат файлы css, файлы с разрешением map - возможно, именно они влияют на то, что ты видишь.

Comment: По поводу css понял. Теперь подробнее о less. Например, я хочу посмотреть, что же не так с моим css, что работает, а что нет. Среди перечисленных стилей появляется стиль, уоторый отображает текущий дизайн, и этот стиль прописан в less. В папке, где лежат css, есть файлы с разрешением map. Я их пробовал удалять, ничего не происходило, хотя я удалял кэш браузера и перезапускал сервер.

Comment: То есть эти файлы (map) там заново появлялись, или же нет?